# Data cleaning/sorting

Tags: python, pandas

Fairly new to coding, learning Python as my first language. I have an Excel file full of data. I'm trying to drop columns I don't need and then sort them by Name maybe. Each column would have its title, and I want to keep a few specific columns and delete the rest. Unsure of how to do that. So far :

```
filename = input('Enter File Name : ')
sheet = input('Enter Sheet name : ')

import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel(io=filename, sheet_name=sheet)
print(df.head)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please format your code properly, [click here to learn how](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Answer (score 0):

Almost all of your questions about pandas are covered in the docs [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/index.html).

`usecols` should help to read only specific columns, you can use ranges like "A:F" or specific column names or a combination of both.

```py
filename = input('Enter File Name : ') 
sheet = input('Enter Sheet name : ')
df = pd.read_excel(filename, sheet_name=sheet, usecols="A:D,F")
```

You can then sort like this,

```py
# if Name is the column name, otherwise just give the columns in a list you want to sort by
df.sort_values(by=['Name'])
```

Also, say you read the entire excel sheet and want to delete columns later

```py
# Just give the list of columns you want to delete
df.drop(['col1', 'col2', 'col3'], inplace=True, axis=1)
```